# Dense_Rank keeps returning each row as 1?

Tags: sql, mysql, window-functions, dense-rank

I am playing around with a Netflix dataset from Kaggle on MySQL. The dataset contains fields such as Country, Subscription_Type, Age, Gender, Monthly_Revenue, etc. In the Subscription_Type column, the possible return fields are Basic, Standard, Premium. I am trying to find the most common subscription type for each country, so I'd ideally have one result per country.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT Country,
            Subscription_Type, 
            COUNT(*) as count_subscription, 
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) as count_subscription FROM netflix) ) as `rnk`
    FROM netflix
    GROUP BY Country, Subscription_Type
) as subscription_rank
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

The problem I'm having is that Dense_Rank is ranking each row as 1, so I end up getting three results per country. How can I fix it so that I'm able to get the most popular subscription type per country?

Comment: `ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) as count_subscription FROM netflix)` has no dependency on the row being ranked. So every row has the same rank.

Comment: Post the data sample and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery is nonsense: it's not correlated so returns the same result on every row.

Moreover, it's not necessary. Window functions work *after* aggregation, so you can just use `COUNT(*)` directly.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT nf.Country,
           nf.Subscription_Type, 
           COUNT(*) as count_subscription, 
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY nf.Country ORDER BY COUNT(*)) as rnk
    FROM netflix nf
    GROUP BY
      nf.Country,
      nf.Subscription_Type
) as subscription_rank
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

I might be wrong, but maybe you wanted `COUNT(*) DESC`? Also `DENSE_RANK` will return tied results, whereas `ROW_NUMBER` does not.